# Grouping array of bits into array of bytes

Tags: matlab

I have an array of bits that is 1 by 240,000 elements long. This array represents a received digital transmission.

I would like to reduce the number of elements to 1, 30,000 where each elements represents 8 bits (or a byte) from the sequence.

Also I would like to do this without using any loops. I have played with the reshape command but I have not been able to get it working.

To clarify with (16 bits instead of 240,000):

```
Input: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1; 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,]
Output: [00000001, 00000010]
```

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This is something you might want to try. The output is in string format, which I guess is what you want all the zeros to show up:

```
clear all;
a = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0];
newsize = length(a)/8;
c = '';
b = cellstr('');
for j = 1:newsize
    c = [c int2str(a((8*(j-1)+1):(8*(j))))];
    b = [b cellstr(c)];
    c = '';
end
b = b(2:end);
```

Only one `for` loop.

Output is:

```
b: ['0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1','0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0']
```

Answer (score 0):

I found converting it to strings via num2str and cellstr and then removing all the white spaces worked okey:

```
i=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1; 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,];

i=cellstr(num2str(i));
o=regexprep(i,'[^\w'']','');
```

Output:
    o =

```
'00000001'
'00000010'
```

Note that the format is still a string now in order to keep all the non-informative leading zeros.

Comment: Unfortunately the num2str function cannot work with the number of bits that I using and ends up truncating my function. I did figure this out though, so I will post the answer.